# UIView Overgive Value

Tags: iphone, uiview

when calling another UIView how can I send a value:

ServerSelect *neu =[[ServerSelect alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:neu animated:NO];

to this view?

Andreas

Comment: Hi @Ploetzeneder. Please indent your code-blocks by four spaces to make it be formatted nicely. (http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `ServerSelect` is an subclass of `UIViewController`? If so, you can just declare a property in the `ServerSelect` class and set the property before you display your view.